# how do i pull data from a spreadsheet and use the value? Node

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'm new to coding and just trying to learn the basics, I've coded a script in node.js which orders simcards from giffgaff, it works great but I'm wanting to be able to pull names and addresses from an excel sheet and I'm stuck on how to do that.
I've inputted xlsxpopulate and when using console.log it logs the value in the spreadsheet but is there a way I can then transfer the value in to another line of my code?
Thanks in advance!
(sorry if I sound a bit uneducated still trying to learn!)

```
XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync("./info.xlsx")
.then(workbook => {


   const value = new Object(workbook.sheet("Sheet1").cell("A1").value());

    



    var searchForm = driver.findElement(By.id('lastname'));
    searchForm.sendKeys(value);
```

});

Comment: Can you post the code you have?

Comment: Can't you simply save what you are outputting to the console to a variable?

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: I've uploaded the code I'm using, i just get the error "value is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need new Object.

```
XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync("./info.xlsx")
.then(workbook => {

   const value = workbook.sheet("Sheet1").cell("A1").value();

   var searchForm = driver.findElement(By.id('lastname'));
   searchForm.sendKeys(value);
});
```